# Deserialize a protobuf serialized data after renaming the base ProtoBuf.Net class;

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I had the below classes in the old version of my application.

**FooBase.cs**

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Baz)]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Qux)]
public abstract class FooBase
{
     [ProtoMember(5)]
     public int Bar { get; set;}
}
```

**Baz.cs**

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Baz : FooBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Quux {get;set;}
}
```

**Qux.cs**

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Qux : FooBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Corge {get;set;}
}
```

Now we have some data serialized using Protobuf.Net to `Bar` and `Qux`

Now, in the next version, we decided to make it possible to serialize to  `FooBase` as well.
So, `FooBase` is no longer an abstract class.

I really want to rename `FooBase` to `Foo`
The question is,
If I rename `FooBase` to `Foo`,

**Foo.cs**

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Baz)]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Qux)]
public class Foo
{
     [ProtoMember(5)]
     public int Bar { get; set;}
}
```

Is it still possible to deserialize my old data to `Baz` and `Qux`?

I could not find any answer from the available documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the binary protocol level, protobuf doesn't talk names; it *exclusively* talks numbers. If you're using code-first, you can change the names *all day long* - it won't matter. You can serialize from `Foo` and deserialize into `NewFooFinal3` - fine. Just don't change the numbers.

(caveat: unless you're using the "dynamic typing" features from v2, that are deprecated in v3)

Comment: Thanks. This clears my  doubt

Comment: Question:  By Code-first, you meant using protobuf-net right?

Comment: @JinsPeter protobuf-net can work code-first or contract-first; by code-first, I mean: the contracts are defined primarily in C# via your own POCO types with attributes, not code that was generated from a .proto file

Comment: Okay, Got the idea